# Frame.Navigate, Frame.GoBack stop working after snap

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm running into a weird issue where after my app has stopped responding to Frame.Navigate requests after the app has been snapped.  I am writing a search app with 3 pages:  a query entry page, a results page, and a result detail page.

Running the query successfully uses `Frame.Navigate(typeof (Results), QueryBox.Text);` to open the results page (Descendant of `LayoutAwarePage`) in both snapped and unsnapped states.

When the search is run from the unsnapped UI, I am able to click on a result and navigate to the details page.  When the search is run from the snapped UI, however, I am unable to actually navigate to the correct page.  After the snapped results page has been loaded it appears that any sort of navigation is completely impossible.  Clicking the back button does not return to the query page (although it does appear to be affecting the navigation stack, as the back button does go away).

Through debugging, I've uncovered the following information:

- The correct button handler code is still being called.  Snapped view and full view are executing the same exact code to launch the details page (`Frame.Navigate(typeof (DetailPopup), pb.PodOwner);`, where DetailPopup is the page, and pb.PodOwner is the data context for the page).
- The constructor for the `DetailPopup` page is actually being called, but the page is still not loading.
- After restoring the snapped page to the unsnapped state, the effect of being unable to navigate persists.
- After commenting out all changes applied in `<VisualState x:Name="Snapped">` of the `Results` page the problem persists
- I've read that there are issues with Frame.Navigate being called from OnNavigatedTo, but  all these interactions are happening well after that method has completed.  Are there other similar caveats for other methods / events?

If there's any code specifically that you'd like to see I'd be happy to post it, but I'm not sure where the offending issue is and posting the entire page source would be kind of overwhelming ;)

Comment: Are you trying to navigate from the `OnNavigatedTo`?

Comment: No, it's navigating from the click listener on a button on the page (which would only be available after OnNavigatedTo, right?

Comment: It sounds to me like an exception is being thrown when trying to navigate. Try running it in the debugger and seeing if you can isolate what error it is. It's very likely an issue with the XAML. Make sure that all named controls referred to in the `VisualState` exist, or remove the reference. The `Navigate` method generally catches exceptions and returns whether or not it succeeded as a `bool`, so it may seem like it just stops working.

Comment: I turned on Break on Exceptions and checked all the options but it didn't break on anything.  Oh, and I've tried storing the result of the `Navigate` call, and it's always been true, even when nothing happened :-/

Comment: Oh, this is interesting.  I ran a perfomance report of the Xaml and got this:  http://gyazo.com/5f9f198ae481e1b0c563864af2631337  So it's creating the pages, just not changing from the current one somehow...